# Py2.7 How fix problem with index out of range?

Tags: python

I'm not into programming, I only use some Python scripts and I have problem with this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mature_homology.py", line 43 (bold bottom) , in 
    mirnas = line[3].split('#')
IndexError: list index out of range

This is the script:

```
    for line in f2:
    line = line.strip().split('\t')
    **mirnas = line[3].split('#')**
for mirna in mirnas:

mirna = mirna.split('|')[0].replace('U', 'T')

mature_mirnas[mirna] = ''
```

Do you have any ideas? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: put the whole code here, we cannot figure it out what is wrong from a single line of code

Comment: What does the file you're trying to read look like?

Comment: A common cause of something like this is a blank line in the file.

Comment: Could you please add your entire code along with what file are you trying to read here so we can see what is going on @LuckyLuck

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, `line[3].split('#')` has size less than 4, hence you cannot access the 4th element using `line[3]`, which throws an error `IndexError: list index out of range`

Make sure you are checking the length of `line` before you try to access the 4th element.

```
for line in f2:
    line = line.strip().split('\t')
    #Check length of line here to be greater than or equal to 4
    if len(line) >= 4:
        mirnas = line[3].split('#')
        ......
```